# Why is sortByKey so slow in spark? Is their any alternative for that?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

Whenever I use **sortByKey** in my program, it hangs! Is their a more efficient way of sorting an RDD in Spark? What about **RangePartitioner**? Is their a way to sort using **RangePartitioner**? My RDD is of type `[(Integer, SomeType)]`. After sorting, I partition my data using **RangePartitioner** and process it further by using **mapPartitions**. In that scenario, what is the most elegant way of sorting the RDD? Basically I want my RDD to be sorted before I start with **mapPartitions**.

Comment: Needs more information about your dataset, and how you have partitioned it. And do you really need to sort?  Often that's just an intermediate step than can be done in another way.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: I've added more information in my question.

Comment: Assuming the integers are randomly distributed across your data set (i.e. your RDD is randomly ordered to start with), sorting will involve n log n comparisons and a lot of data movement between nodes. It's always going to take significant time (O(n log n),  but with a significant constant factor as data movement is expensive)

Comment: So, how can we improve this? Any suggestions? Does RangePartitioner do any sort of sorting? Even if all elements of one partition are less than all the elements of the next partition, I'm OK with it. Does RangePartitioner do that?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul On average it can do better than _O(n log n)_. It is basically a bucket sort after all. Not that it helps anything when you have to move all the data around. Pythonic -`RangePartitioner` is unlikely to help you. The only thing you omit this way is a local sort which shouldn't be very expensive as long as there is no large data skew.

Comment: That maybe it as well ! Is the data distribution skewed ?

Comment: Doesn't sortbykey actually sort the complete RDD then? I must have misunderstood.

Comment: If you look at the source, sortByKey uses RangePartitioner,so using it again is really unlikely to help? It would really help to know what your actual use-case is here...

Answer (score 2):

Spark is not made for sorting.
If it hangs, means you are trying to sort over very big dataset.

Ask yourself, what will you do with millions of sorted resultset?
Use takeOrdered instead.